# Removing program after accidentally removed its installation folder

Tags: software-installation, uninstall

How can I remove or reinstall a program after I accidentally removed its installation folder?

I accidentally removed `/opt/spotify/`folder and I cannot reinstall `spotify-client` nor purge it.

```
 sudo apt-get purge spotify-client
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 The following packages will be REMOVED:
   spotify-client*
 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 45 not upgraded.
 1 not fully installed or removed.
 After this operation, 143 MB disk space will be freed.
 Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
 (Reading database ... 276312 files and directories currently installed.)
 Removing spotify-client (1:0.9.17.1.g9b85d43.7-1) ...
 /var/lib/dpkg/info/spotify-client.prerm: 9: cd: can't cd to /opt/spotify/spotify-client
 dpkg: error processing package spotify-client (--purge):
  subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 2
 /var/lib/dpkg/info/spotify-client.postinst: 5: cd: can't cd to /opt/spotify/spotify-client
 dpkg: error while cleaning up:
  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
 Errors were encountered while processing:
  spotify-client
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall spotify-client
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 45 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for spotify-client:amd64
```

Of course, the folder is not in the trash! Thanks!

Comment: Manually create the directory `/opt/spotify/spotify-client` and then try to purge. See what happens..

Comment: Not working, kind of same problem (it looks for stuff inside the new empty folder!)

Comment: what happens with `sudo apt-get install spotify-client`?

Comment: Exactly the same message as I wrote in the main question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get around the situation by using a combination of `apt` and `dpkg`. First download the deb package from repository

```
apt-get download <packagename>
```

Then install the .deb file (it's in current folder)

```
sudo dpkg -i <downloaded_package_file.deb>
```

If this doesn't work, add the `--force-all` switch to `dpkg`, i.e.

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all <downloaded_package_file.deb>
```

If it still doesn't work, also add `--no-triggers`

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all --no-triggers <downloaded_package_file.deb>
```

As a last resort **(not recommended)**, you could manually edit `/var/lib/dpkg/status`:

- make a backup of the file
- find and delete the block regarding `spotify-client`
- keep the empty line before the next block
- save
- `apt-get -f install spotify-client`

Comment: It did not work. `[...]
/var/lib/dpkg/info/spotify-client.prerm: 9: cd: can't cd to /opt/spotify/spotify-client
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 2
[...]
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 spotify-client_1%3a0.9.17.1.g9b85d43.7-1_amd64.deb`

Comment: Added my answer.

Comment: So, I tried with `--force-all` and `--no-triggers` but nothing.. still the same error. Not sure about the not recommended one. Maybe I will wait for other users ideas! ;)

Comment: It seems like the `not recommended` solution worked! Thanks a lot! ;)

Comment: I worded it that way to make clear that this is a last resort, something you try when you're desperate ;-) Good to hear it worked!

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is get a file listing of the package and then wipe out all those files, then reinstall:

1. Remove: `apt-get remove spotify-client`
2. Purge files completely: `apt-file list spotify-client | cut -d' ' -f 2 | xargs rm -rf`
3. Then reinstall: `apt-get install spotify-client`

Comment: Point 1 did not work. `dpkg: error processing package spotify-client (--remove):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
Errors were encountered while processing:
 spotify-client
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`. Point 2: `sudo: apt-file: command not found`.